# Best way to automate the page/post publication process?

Tags: automation

I'm working on a spreadsheet that has the contact information for thousands of training programs related to my niche. I'm wondering if any of you know a way to automate the process of creating a landing page for each entry. Each page will contain:

1. School name
2. School address
3. School phone number
4. School website
5. School accreditation date

Since this is a very routine process, there must be a way to automate it all instead of posting 3,000+ landing pages. Let me know if you have any suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: This looks like a request that belongs more on a job board for hiring a consultant.

Comment: If you upload the spreadsheet I can create you a wordpress export that you can import on your site, no problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [CSV Importer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/csv-importer/other_notes/)  plugin to import your spreadsheet into posts or even better a custom post type say "school" import school name as post title and the rest as custom fields.  Then create a single-school.php file in your theme directory and pull out the name and other fields and you are done.
Each school will have Its own page

Comment: +1. Just make a custom post type for that and export it using the core WordPress exporter Plugin. This will show you which format you need.